# When the Gorenstein dimension of dual module is finite?

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $R$ a commutative semiperfect Noetherian ring and $M$ a finitely generated R-module. Denote $G$-dim($M$) the Gorenstein dimension of $M$. Under which assumptions about ring R is valid:

$G$-dim($M$) finite implies $G$-dim($M^*$) finite?

I know it's valid when $G$-dim($M$)$=0$, but I do not know if it's worth for positive Gorenstein dimensions.

Comment: What is the definie of Gorebstein dimension?